# Call Recording Other side voice volume is very low in recorded file

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder, call-recording

This is the function called in a service for call recording.

```
try{        
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();     

    file = File.createTempFile("" + cal.getTime(), ".amr", fileDirPath);

    this.phoneCall.setPathToRecording(file.getAbsolutePath());

    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);

    mediaRecorder.setAudioChannels(1);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(8000);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(12200);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
    mediaRecorder.prepare();
    mediaRecorder.start();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Tested with SAMSUNG, LENOVO, GIONEE Works fine.

The problem occurs in the MOTOROLA and MI devices

What code is need to be change to get proper other person sound in the recoded file

Comment: are you trying sip call recording

Comment: No I just use an broadcast with action


   <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
to know call is done

Comment: @MithunHalmare hii did you get any solution?\

Comment: No i am still searching